# can't return variable from class

Tags: c#

```
 class cAccess
    {
        private static string usn1;

        public static string usnt
        {
            set
            {
                usn1 = value;
            }
            get
            {
                string[] s = new string[3];
                DataSet dsa = new DataSet();
                SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter();
                adp.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from access where id=" + usn1, connection.setCon());
                adp.Fill(dsa, "t");
                DataRow DBrow = dsa.Tables["t"].Rows[0];
                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                {
                    s[i] = DBrow.ItemArray.GetValue(i).ToString();
                }
                return s;
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to return `s` array from class but when I start debugging, it shows this error:

> The name 's' does not exist in the current context. Code works true
>   but can't return s.

Comment: You are not trying to return array from class, but from get accessor of `usnt` property, which has the type of `String` ?!?.  It is not possible and meaningless.
May be you need a method?

Comment: The code you posted won't even compile, never mind be debuggable. Without an actual code example and a more specific problem description, it's going to be hard to answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

you can't return a `string[]` to `string`!

Try:

```
class cAccess
{
    private static string usn1;

    public string usnt
    {
      set
      {
        usn1 = value;
      }
      get
      {
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
        DataSet dsa = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter();
        adp.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from access where id=" + usn1, connection.setCon());
        adp.Fill(dsa, "t");
        DataRow DBrow = dsa.Tables["t"].Rows[0];
       for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
       {
         s.Append(DBrow.ItemArray.GetValue(i).ToString());
       }

       usn1 = s.ToString();
       return(usn1);
 }
```

Comment: Well, it wouldn't say "The name 's' does not exist in the current context" if this was the primary case.

Comment: @ardaozkal : sorry! didn't pay attention to that, my answer is updated

Comment: This might work but the example code is so bad so I can't test it

Comment: @ardaozkal: well letting the sql part away, you can test it of course. just `s.Append("foo");` will be enough [here is a fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QDx8Gg)